# Showing $\exp:\mathscr{O}_X\to\mathscr{O}_X^*$ is an epimorphism of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

$\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}$Let $X=\Bbb{C}$. Define $\O_X$ to be the sheaf of holomorphic functions, and $\O_X^*$ to be the sheaf of invertible (i.e. nonvanishing) holomorphic functions, the latter of which we consider as an abelian group under multiplication. Define $\exp:\O_X\to\O_X^*$ by $\exp(U)(f)(z)=\exp(f(z))$ for $f\in\O_X(U)$, $z\in\Bbb{C}$.

I'm trying to show that $\exp$ is an epimorphism in the category of sheaves on $X$. This is equivalent to showing that for all $p\in X$, the induced map on stalks $\exp_p:\O_{x,p}\to\O_{x,p}^*$ is a surjection as a set map. This means that given any $g_p\in\O_{x,p}^*(U)$, there exists $f_p\in\O_{x,p}$ such that $g_p=\exp_p(U)(f_p)=\exp(U)(f)_p=\exp(f)_p$.

This amounts to saying that every nonvanishing function has a "local logarithm". I don't know how to show this is the case though, using the fact that $g_p$ is nonvanishing on $U$. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

(if it matters at all, I'm using Vakil's notes.)

Comment: Well, think back to complex analysis. You can define a logarithm after removing a ray emanating from origin in the complex plane. If you have some nonvanishing $f\colon (U \ni P) \to \mathbb C$ then you can make your ray miss $f(P)$. Now use continuity and the fact that you're allowed to shrink $U$.

Comment: Okay I think I see now. So, if I let say $L$ be any ray from from $0$ which misses $g(p)$ (which exists because $g(p)\neq0$), I can let $U'=U\setminus L$, which is open. Then $f=\log(g)$ exists on $U'$, and therefore $\exp(f)_p=g_p$ because they agree on the neighborhood $U'$ of $p$, so $\exp_p$ is surjective. Is there anything wrong with that? It doesn't feel quite right to me.

Comment: You have to show (using continuity) that $g$ misses the ray not only at $p$ but on all of some open subset $U' \subset U$. So your choice of $U'$ is wrong.

Comment: @MooS would this work: let $r=d(g(p),L)$, so that $B_r(f(p))$ is a neighborhood of $f(p)$ which does not intersect $L$. Then by continuity of $g$ at $p$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ such that $g(V)\subseteq B_r(f(p))$, and hence $g$ has a logarithm on the set $V$